# Is Google font api supported in all current and old browsers?

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api

Is Google font api supported in all current and old browsers?

and will it work if js is disabled.?

- IE6
- IE7
- IE8
- Firefox 3.0+
- Safari
- Chrome
- iPhone/iPad
- Blackberry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>99% sure will not work if js is disabled.</strike>

As for browser compatibility, I ran a [Litmus test](http://litmusapp.com) for you which you can check out [here](http://salted.litmusapp.com/pub/bcf1d19).  Also checked on my iphone and ipad and it looks good which makes sense since that basically is using Safari.  Looks like older versions of Firefox are the only thing with issues.

Not too sure about Blackberry - sorry.

Also from their FAQ:

> **What browsers are supported?**
>
> ```
> The Google Font API is compatible with the following browsers:
>
>     * Google Chrome: version 4.249.4+
>     * Mozilla Firefox: version: 3.5+
>     * Apple Safari: version 3.1+
>     * Opera: version 10.5+
>     * Microsoft Internet Explorer: version 6+
> ```
>
> The Google Font API is not currently
>   supported on iPhone, iPad, iPod, or
>   Android.

Comment: Just tested they are working even if js is disabled. It's cool

Comment: I doubt the BlackBerry browser supports font replacement; I've heard multiple reports that the support for complex webpages isn't great.

Comment: @brendan - but you wrote "my iphone and ipad and it looks good "

Comment: It does - despite them not officially supporting those devices their test page looks fine.